# Need help writing JS code for images that onclick display different elements on page

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, display

I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I have some troubles trying to write this code.

I want to have four images on my page that onclick show different articles (each article should be shown in the same place). So for example when I click pic no.1 it shows article no.1, then when I click pic no.3 it show article no.3 in the place of the previous article.

The simplest way I know is to write different functions for each image/article, so this would be the code for the first image which shows the first article:

```
<script>
    function showArticle() {
    document.getElementById("firstArticle").style.display='block';}
</script>
```

All images would have the *onclick* event that 'calls' the function and displays the article

```
<img onclick="showArticle()" ... />
```

And each article would have a different *id* and *display* property set to *none*

```
<article style="display:none" id="firstArticle">
```

Also I should add a function that hides the article when another article is about to be shown but I'm not sure how to put it all together. So my question is: Do I have to write seperate functions for all images and articles or can I do it another way and have only one function which show (and hides) different articles depending on which image I click? If yes then how can I do it?

Edit: This is html for the page (it has some element written in polish, it's not finished, and has external style sheets so I hope it doesn't make it harder to help me ;) )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
     <link rel="icon" href="ikony/favicon.png" type="image/ico">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="kartazezdjeciem.css"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif|Roboto">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Kakaowe love | Przepisy</title>
     <script>
         function pokazPrzepis() {
         document.getElementById("przepisMuffiny").style.display='block';}
     </script>   
     <style>
         body {
             background-image: url("zdjecia/kakao8.jpg");
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: center top;
             background-attachment: fixed; 
             background-size: cover;}
             
         article {
             display: flex;
             justify-content: space-between;
             padding: 0 10%;}
         
         article:first-child {
             padding-bottom: 5%;}
                     
         .muffiny {
             background-image: url("zdjecia/muffiny.jpg");} 
         
         .czekoladadopicia {
             background-image: url("zdjecia/czekoladadopicia.jpg");}    
         
         .kakaodopicia {
             background-image: url("zdjecia/kakaodopicia.jpg");}    
        
         .kolumny {
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: row;
             justify-content: space-between;
             border-radius: 16px;
             background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.6);
             box-shadow:  5px 5px 20px rgb(0,0,0,0.6);
             padding: 1.5% 3%;}
             
         .kolumny ul {
             list-style-type: none;}

         .kolumny ul, ol {
             text-align: left;
             padding: 0;
             margin: 0;}
             
         .kolumny ul li {
             margin: 10px 0;}
         
         .kolumny ol li {
             margin: 20px 0;}   
     </style>
</head>  
<body>
     <header>   
         <nav> 
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="witamy.html">WITAMY</a></li>                   
                 <li><a class="aktywna" href="przepisy.html">PRZEPISY</a></li>               
                 <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>  
                 <img src="zdjecia/logo2.png"/>              
                 <li><a href="sklep.html">SKLEP</a></li>
                 <li class="listarozwijana">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="polelisty">O KAKAO</a>
                     <div class="zawartosclisty">
                         <a href="historiakakao.html">HISTORIA</a>
                         <a href="produkcjakakao.html">PRODUKCJA</a>
                     </div>
                 </li>
                 <li class="listarozwijana">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="polelisty">O CZEKOLADZIE</a>
                     <div class="zawartosclisty">
                         <a href="historiaczekolady.html">HISTORIA</a>
                         <a href="produkcjaczekolady.html">PRODUKCJA</a>
                     </div>
                 </li>               
             </ul> 
         </nav> 
     </header>
     <main>
         <article>
             <div class="kartazezdjeciem" onclick="pokazPrzepis()">      
                     <div class="zdjeciekarty kakaodopicia"></div>               
                 <div class="opiskarty">
                     <h4>Kakao do picia</h4>
                     <p>..</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="kartazezdjeciem" onclick="pokazPrzepis()">
                     <div class="zdjeciekarty czekoladadopicia"></div>
                 <div class="opiskarty">
                     <h4>Czekolada do picia</h4>
                     <p>...</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="kartazezdjeciem" onclick="pokazPrzepis()">
                     <div class="zdjeciekarty muffiny"></div>
                 <div class="opiskarty">
                     <h4>Muffiny czekoladowe</h4>
                     <p>...</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="kartazezdjeciem" onclick="pokazPrzepis()">
                     <div class="zdjeciekarty"></div>                
                 <div class="opiskarty">
                     <h4>Ciasto</h4>
                     <p>...</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </article>  
         <article style="display:none" id="przepisKako">
             <div class="kolumny">
                 <div style="width:25%">
                     <h3>Składniki:</h3>
                     <ul>
                         <li>400 ml mleka</li>
                         <li>2 łyżki miodu</li>
                         <li>3 łyżki cukru</li>
                         <li>4 łyżki gorzkiego kakao</li>
                         <li>6kostek czekolady (gorzkiej lub mlecznej) </li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div style="width:72%">
                     <h3>Przygotowanie:</h3>
                     <ol>
                         <li>Mleko zagrzej z cukrem, odlej odrobinę do szklanki.</li>
                         <li>Wymieszaj przelane mleko z kakao i dodaj z powrotem do garnka. Zagotuj, cały czas mieszając.</li>
                         <li>Napój przelej do kubków, dodaj miód i startą na tarce czekoladę!</li>
                     </ol>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </article>
         <article style="display:none" id="przepisMuffiny">
             <div class="kolumny">
                 <div style="width:25%">
                     <h3>Składniki:</h3>
                     <ul>
                         <li>150 g masła</li>
                         <li>150 g czekolady (dowolnej)</li>
                         <li>300 g mąki</li>
                         <li>2 łyżeczki proszku do pieczenia</li>
                         <li>1/2 łyżeczki sody oczyszczonej</li>
                         <li>2 łyżki kakao</li>
                         <li>1 łyżka kawy zbożowej lub kakao</li>
                         <li>1 szklanka (190 g) cukru</li>
                         <li>1 łyżka cukru wanilinowego lub 2 łyżeczki ekstraktu z wanilii</li>
                         <li>2 duże jajka</li>
                         <li>170 ml mleka</li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div style="width:72%">
                     <h3>Przygotowanie:</h3>
                     <ol>
                         <li>Piekarnik nagrzać do 180 stopni C. Masło roztopić i ostudzić. Czekoladę pokroić na kawałeczki.</li>
                         <li>Mąkę przesiać do miski razem z proszkiem do pieczenia, sodą, kakao, kawą zbożową. Jeszcze raz przesiać w celu dokładnego wymieszania składników. Dodać cukier, cukier wanilinowy, wymieszać, odstawić.</li>
                         <li>Jajka rozmiksować w drugiej misce razem z mlekiem i ekstraktem z wanilii (jeśli nie używaliśmy cukru wanilinowego).</li>
                         <li>Teraz wszystkie składniki delikatnie łączymy za pomocą łyżki: do sypkich, przesianych składników dodajemy masę jajeczną i kilkakrotnie delikatnie mieszamy łyżką, dodajemy roztopione masło a za chwilę posiekaną czekoladę. Mieszamy krótko (3 - 4 ruchy łyżką), ciasto ma być lekko grudkowate, ale surowa mąka nie powinna być widoczna.</li>
                         <li>Masę wyłożyć do papilotek umieszczonych w formie na muffiny i wstawić do piekarnika. Piec przez około 25 minut, do czasu aż muffiny urosną, na wierzchu utworzy się skorupka a wetknięty patyczek będzie suchy.</li>
                     </ol>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </article>
         <article style="display:none" id="przepisCzekolada">
         </article>
         <article style="display:none" id="przepisCiasto">
         </article>
     </main>     
     <footer>
         <div class="kolumnystopka">
             <div>
                 Autor: Julia Wróblewska wrgreg<br>awefwfeef
             </div>
             <div>
             Font generated by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com"> flaticon.com</a>.<br>
             Under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/">CC</a>: 
             <a data-file="015-cocoa-6" href="http://www.freepik.com">Freepik</a>, 
             <a data-file="004-cocoa-2" href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/vitaly-gorbachev">Vitaly Gorbachev</a>, 
             <a data-file="008-chocolate" href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/ddara">dDara</a> 
             </div>
         </div>
     </footer>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I gave you a solution. Did you need it?

Comment: Thank you! It's great, that's exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Do you have any questions or requests?

Comment: I don't have any, thanks :)

Comment: Ok, and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you need happens in this code. By clicking on the picture, you get the text corresponding to the index.

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('.images img');
let text = document.querySelectorAll('.content .text');

img.forEach(function (img_current, index) {
  img_current.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    text[i].classList.remove('visible');
  } 
    text[index].classList.add('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.text.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
  <img src="https://www.ejin.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/fshshshshshshshsh-e1542184507336.jpg">
  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/2000885/1902/i/600/depositphotos_19021343-stock-photo-red-heart.jpg">
  <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline styles, its easier to change elements visibility with classes. In CSS add a class that assigns "display: block" to the article.

```
article {
  display: none;
}
article.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

You can write one single function that targets the article that needs to be shown based on the clicked image data attributes.

Before finding the article to show, just find the article that has the "visible" class, and remove it.

After that, add the "visible" class to the article that is connected to the clicked image.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const handleImageClick = (event) => {
    const previouslyVisibleArticle = document.querySelector(".visible");
    if (previouslyVisibleArticle) {
      previouslyVisibleArticle.classList.remove("visible");
    }

    const id = event.target.dataset.index;
    const articleId = "article-" + id;
    const article = document.getElementById(articleId);
    article.classList.add("visible");
  };

  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  images.forEach((image) => image.addEventListener("click", handleImageClick));
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.images img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.images img:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

article {
  display: none;
}
article.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="images">
    <img data-index="1" src="https://dummyimage.com/75/000/fff&text=1"/>
    <img data-index="2" src="https://dummyimage.com/75/000/fff&text=2"/>
    <img data-index="3" src="https://dummyimage.com/75/000/fff&text=3"/>
    <img data-index="4" src="https://dummyimage.com/75/000/fff&text=4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="articles">
    <article class="visible" id="article-1">
      <h2>article 1</h2>
      <p>Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
    </article>
    <article id="article-2">
      <h2>article 2</h2>
      <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.</p>
    </article>
    <article id="article-3">
      <h2>article 3</h2>
      <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
    </article>
    <article id="article-4">
      <h2>article 4</h2>
      <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```